# Можно ли запустить chromedriver без открытия самого окна?

Tags: python

У меня есть код, который заходит на страницу в Vk. Хочу узнать, можно ли зайти на неё без открытия консоли и без открытия самого браузера chromedriver

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://vk.com/im")#ссылка на сайт, который нужно вписать
_login=browser.find_element(By.ID,"email")#строка для ввода логина
_login.send_keys("login")#ввод логина в строку
_pass=browser.find_element(By.ID,"pass")#строка для ввода пароля
_pass.send_keys("password")
_login_button=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[id="login_button"]').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется headless режим:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome("путь к драйверу", chrome_options=options)
```